# How to turn off the Ubuntu 13.04 window fade effect

Tags: 13.04, window-manager

When I minimize an application it is very slow, due to my slow laptop

It's quite frustrating to see it very slowly creep out of view!

So how can I it turned off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do so using the Unity Tweak tool.  If you don't have it installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Once installed, search for it in dash, click on it.  Once it comes up, click on Window Manager --> General.  See image below.

[image]

Once the new window open up, click on Animation, and choose None under Minimize.  See image below.

[image]

Note: You may have to close the applications and open it again for it to work.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Also working on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: For Ubuntu 15.04+, if you get an error about `com.canonical.unity.webapps`, you'll also need to install `unity-webapps-common` if you get