# What causes application window to 'fade'?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz

All,

*(using Ubuntu 12.04. Issue shows Firefox 28, but has occured with various applications)*

In the image below, Firefox seemed to have 'faded' after a script error

I have experienced this with other applications, but decided to capture it and post here after seeing it once again.

Tonight a script on a webpage stop responding, and after 'stopping' the script, the window lost its colour saturation:

[image: image on left after script crash, image on right normal colour saturation]

(image on left after script crash, image on right normal colour saturation)

Is this a known issue?

-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is by design, to notify user that the program is not working as expected.

Not only firefox, all the application in ubuntu exhibit the same behavior.

(Much like `Not Responding` window in Win OS)

If want you can turn it off, Here are two ways

[How to turn off the Ubuntu 13.04 window fade effect](https://askubuntu.com/q/312874/35775)

[How do I turn off the feature where a window grays out when it's thinking?](https://askubuntu.com/q/128921/35775)

Comment: is right it is unity`s feature to notify to not to tolerate that application while it is busy.